# Stabilising chain of submodules

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Take $S$ to be a commutative ring with unit, and $N \subset M$ to be $S$-modules. I am interested in the necessary and sufficient condition for it to be the case that for every collection of submodules $\{M_i\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$, such that $M_i \cap N = 0$, they form a stabilising chain,

$$M_1 \subset M_2 \subset \cdots \subset M_{n}.$$

I believe a necessary and sufficient condition is that every $M_i$ such that $M_i\cap N=0$ is finitely generated. I know that if every submodule was finitely generated, then $M$ would be Noetherian, and thus I am guaranteed this stabilising chain.

However, if I am only requiring that $M_i$'s such that $M_i \cap N = 0$ be finitely generated, this does not exclude the possibility of submodules which are not finitely generated to exist in $M$ so $M$ is not being required to be Noetherian, and so I am not guaranteed this stabilising chain. How can I approach this?

Comment: Are you looking for necessary and sufficient conditions on $M$ that make this true for every $N$, or necessary and sufficient conditions on the pair $M$ and $N$ together? Edit: I realize you mean the latter, since in the former take $N = \{ \}$ and this reduces to requiring $M$ Noetherian.

Comment: Shouldn't the intersection of any two submodules contain the identity?

Comment: @jwimberley Said differently, let $M$ have property $P$ if every ascending chain of submodules intersecting to zero with $N$ stabilises. Then my question is showing property $P$ if and only if every module intersecting to zero with $N$ is finitely generated.

Comment: I realize now $M_i \cap N = 0$ means that their intersection is the zero-module -- sorry, the notation looked a bit like saying their intersection was the empty set when I didn't read too closely.

Comment: *Every chain of submodules of $M$ which intersect $N$ trivially stablizates iff every submodule of $M$ which intersect $N$ trivially is finitely generated.* (The proof is similar to the one for characterizing the Noetherian modules.)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This answer is completely wrong, so don't bother reading it. I'll leave it up for the record; details are in the comments, but I amateurishly confused the set $M \setminus N \cup \{ 0 \}$ with the submodule that it generates.

Let $M_N$ be the smallest submodule of $M$ containing $\left( M \setminus N \right) \cup \{ 0 \}$. The submodules of $M_N$ are exactly the submodules $M_i \leq M$ s.t. $M_i \cap N = \{ 0 \}$. The property in question is thus equivalent to whether $M_N$ is Noetherian or not. There are two cases.

- Trivially, $M_N$ could simply be $M$ itself, i.e. $M$ has a generating set in $M \setminus N$.
- $M_N$ could be a proper submodule of $M$. Since $M \setminus M_N = N \setminus \{ 0 \}$, this works out to say that at least one non-identity of element $N$ cannot be written as a linear combination of elements of $M_N$ over $S$.

Comment: @JPhy Maybe I'm missing something obvious. The definition of a Noetherian module is that all chains of submodules stabilize. All chains of submodules of $M_N$ are in one-to-one correspondence with chains of submodules of $M$ that trivially intersect $N$, and thus $M_N$ is Noetherian iff all such chains proposed by the OP stabilize. Also, assuming axiom of choice, $M_N$ is Noetherian iff all its submodules are finitely generated.

Comment: unfortunately I don't think this is quite right; it's not the case that the submodules of $M_N$ necessarily have zero intersection with $N$. for instance, consider $M=\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and let $N=2\mathbb{Z}$. then the only submodule of $M$ containing $M\setminus N$ is all of $M$; indeed, $M\setminus N$ contains $1$, and hence the submodule it generates contains $\mathbb{Z}\cdot 1=\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: (as another example, note that any two non-zero ideals in an integral domain have non-zero intersection. so, for instance, let $M$ be any non-noetherian integral domain considered as a module over itself – for concreteness say $M=\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ – and let $N$ be any non-finitely generated ideal – for concreteness say $N=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$. then, using your notation, $M_N=M$ is non-noetherian, but $M$ and $N$ satisfy the condition specific by OP. indeed, the _only_ ideal of $M$ that has zero intersection with $N$ is the zero ideal.)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks for taking the time to read through and point out the issues in my answer; clearly I bit off more than I could chew

Comment: no worries at all; easy mistake to make! :)